# Need to pass ArrayList from servlet class to js function

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I am doing pagination in my project. I have a ArrayList in servlet class which has 50 records. I need to show 10 records per page. I am able to get first 10 records in the jsp. However, when I click on the next button I want the records 11-20 from the same ArrayList. Hence I need to cache the ArrayList somewhere. I have tried a number of methods and ways to pass the ArrayList from jsp to js function and from servlet to js function but no luck. Can someone tell me how can I cache the ArrayList so that I can iterate it next time? Any link or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you displaying it to table ? If yes use jquery `Datatable`. `Ajax` is the you get `ArrayList` from `server` to `js` function

Comment: I'm not saying that this question is particularly bad, but pagination as a problem has long since been solved.  Without knowing how you're getting the data in the first place (REST or database), it's tough to begin to suggest a solution.

Comment: @Makoto I am using JDBC connected and storing the resultset values in the ArrayList of a class type. I want to pass this ArrayList in js function.

Comment: @Karanmehta, If you want achieve pagination with technical then you should pick technologies that can support. In your case you are handling Pagination in server side that's a good point and next time if user clicks any page to see its contents send an request to servlet with querystring to mention which page is user clicked. Based on the queryString response back with results from database.. dont try to store all records in servlet.

Answer (score 0):

To pass ArrayList from Servlet to js function in JSP file you need to convert the ArrayList to JSON with Gson. Gson is an open source Java library to serialize and deserialize Java objects to (and from) JSON.

First you need to add gson jar to your project
[download here](http://java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm)

Then convert ArrayList to JSON.

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(yourArrayListName);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

And then you can use it in your ajax function in JSP.

Comment: ....This is working. Now when I get the response in ajax as responseJSON its giving me undefined result while responseText is giving me the ArrayList like this...

Comment: [{"versionname":"Karan",
"versiondesc":"",
"versionreason":"Something",
"versionpath":"A/B/C/D",
"versionappid":30},
{"versionname":"Harsh",
"versiondesc":"",
"versionreason":"2",
"versionSVNpath":"E/D/F/V",
"versionappid":301}]

Comment: Now how do I parse this because it is not a JSON hence JSON parser wont work here